# Writing thread safe containers

Tags: c++, multithreading

Could someone recommend good book on how to write thread safe containers?
thanks

Comment: You could draw inspiration from the `java.util.concurrent` containers...

Comment: come on guys don't close it, it is a perfectly valid question

Comment: +1 to compensate the downvote, it is a valid Q, If being closed as a duplicate, one should say so here in comments.

Comment: @Als: it's not being voted a dupe -- if you click the "close" link, you can see the numbers of votes without having to vote yourself.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Thanks for the tip Steve, 2 votes for `Not a real question` & 1 vote for `Too Localized`, However, I don't see how it is not a real or Localized Q.

Comment: @Als: the only thing I can think is that the definition of "on-topic" changes over time according to convention and taste. Book recommendation lists are far less popular than they used to be.

Comment: @all_who_voted_to_close as a 'not a real question': are you crazy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[STL port](http://www.stlport.org/product.html)** is one STL implementation which offers thread safety, you might want to check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Thread safe containers are **no silver bullet**!

E.g. this code is not thread safe, whatever container you use:

```
if (!container.has(value)) container.add(value);
```

Neither is:

```
container[value] = container[value] + 42;
```

Code can be made thread safe, but it requires a lot more than thread safe containers.

It's even worse: thread safe containers won't buy you much. They may help for simple cases you'll find in text books, but in the more complicated cases that exist in practice, **you will need a lock anyway** (see above for typical cases). Using a thread safe container in that case will be purely overhead.

Have a look at Java, as it started with thread safe containers. After a couple of years Java switched to thread unsafe containers and deprecated the old, thread safe, containers.

So my advice: do not look for thread safe containers. Instead, **look for a good book how to write thread safe code**.

**UPDATE** for clarification: I'm talking about the standard containers, like vector, map, and string.

Comment: I agree it's not a silver bullet but could work some easy tasks where there is no big performance pressure. You can also get rid of some of the outside locking with a good API, for your example you could extend the container's interface with an addIfNotExist() and an addValue() method. For a queue you where you need to lock to check whether the queue is empty and if not pop a value you can write a popBlocking() which will wait while the queue is not empty or write a popIfExists() which will return some specified value if the queue is empty (eg: NULL if you store pointers)

Comment: @yi_H Indeed, good API design is very important, but the devil is in the details and those details depend on the requirements. Thus, IMHO, you end up designing some thread-safe API for your application (using a non thread safe containers for the implementation) anyway. I agree that one usually ends up with some addIfNotExist() or addValue(), disguised under another name. However, my point is that implementing a thread-safe version of a standard container's API (e.g. vector, map, string) won't help much.

Comment: @yi_H E.g. an addValue() won't help much when calculating interest, so let's add a multiplyBy() to the generic API? But what if there is a different rate for positive and negative accounts? And so on.

Comment: You could create an updateWithFunctor(), that's quite generic. I just noted that this approach is good for simple tasks. If you need high concurrency, building thread safety from the bottom (adding locking to basic data structures and then on top of that and so on..) will kill performance.

Answer (score 1):

[1024cores.net](http://www.1024cores.net/) is chock full of good articles about writing thread safe code.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for materiel on [lock-free data structures](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CGQQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.98.3363%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=tb8eTtKqFMj50gHK95SWAw&usg=AFQjCNE3MB_eqQxW_mfO0njCtA-28FgrxA) and [non-blocking algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm). ([Another article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/lwsync.aspx).)

It's common enough to learn about critical sections and so on, but lock-free concurrent methods work well when there are many reads and few writes.

Algorithms of this kind share a lot of common ground with important concepts such as reentrancy and exception safety.

Speaking more broadly, thread safety has a lot do do with **data dependencies** and models of ownership. The upshot of it is that thread-safe programs are relatively easy to write if they've been well-designed in other respects. IMHO a holistic approach to good design pays dividends -- ***get your data right first***, after that, the code comes easily.